# When trying to use the "+=" opperator, will not add on to the variable

Tags: python-3.x, operator-keyword

I am trying to make it so that when the user or the bot wins the round they get a point but at the end of the game, it seems to not add when one or the other gets it right, i tried the other way ('x = x + 1'), also please rate my code and tell me what i could've done better.

```
import random

print('Lets play Rock Paper Scissors')

for tries in range (1,4):

    try:
        user_guess = input('Rock Paper Scissors? ')
        choices = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
        user_point = 0     #To keep track of the points 
        bot_point = 0     
        bot_guess  = random.choice(choices) #Will randomly pick from the list 'choices'

        while user_guess not in choices:#if the user tries to put in anything other then the choices given
            print('Please enter the choices above!')
            user_guess = input('Rock Paper Scissors? ')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please choose from the choices above ')  #Just in case user tries to put a different value type 
        user_guess = input('Rock Paper Scissors? ')

    DEBUG = "The bot did " + bot_guess

    print(DEBUG)

    if user_guess == bot_guess:
        print('Tie!')

    elif user_guess == "Rock" and bot_guess == "Paper":
        print('The bot earns a point!')
        bot_point += 1 

    elif user_guess == 'Paper' and bot_guess == "Rock":
        print('The user earns a point!')
        user_point += 1 

    elif user_guess == 'Paper' and  bot_guess == 'Scissors':
        print('The bot earns a point')
        bot_point += 1 

    elif user_guess == 'Scissors' and bot_guess == 'Paper':
        print('The user earns a point')
        user_point += 1 

    elif user_guess == 'Rock' and  bot_guess == 'Scissors':
        print('The user earns a point')
        user_point += 1 

    elif user_guess == 'Scissors' and bot_guess == 'Rock': 
        print('The bot earns a point')
        bot_point += 1




print('After ' + str(tries) + ' tries. ' + ' The score is')
print('The User: ' + str(user_point))
print('The Bot: ' + str(bot_point))

if user_point > bot_point:
    print('THE USER IS THE WINNER!!!')
else:
    print('THE BOT IS THE WINNER!!!')
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre]. This is a lot of code that's mostly irrelevant to the problem, and it turns out `+=` isn't even the problem, based on bashBedlam's answer. As well, if you want overall advice, that's off-topic here but you could try [codereview.se] instead. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Ok thank You! I will improve upon this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize user_point and bot_point before you start the `for` loop. The way it is, those are reset to zero each time through the loop.

Comment: @Thy.noob It's not the way that I would go about it but that doesn't make it "wrong". Keep going 'cause we all get better as we go ;)